# How do I install Gateio/Gateapi-php Without conflict; require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.2 found ^7.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php, guzzle, php-8

I am trying to install the package but it keeps conflicting with my guzzlehttp/guzzle package which must be version ^7.* due to dependencies from other packages that rely on the guzzle package.

How do I resolve this?

This is the full error below;

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires gateio/gateapi-php ^5.40 -> satisfiable by gateio/gateapi-php[5.40.0].
    - gateio/gateapi-php 5.40.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.2).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require gateio/gateapi-php:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require gateio/gateapi-php:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

When I ran the command with the `-W` flag, the result below is what I got;

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires gateio/gateapi-php ^5.40 -> satisfiable by gateio/gateapi-php[5.40.0].
    - gateio/gateapi-php 5.40.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.2).

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require gateio/gateapi-php:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require gateio/gateapi-php:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: If the other packages can't use the 7 version, you can't use gateio

Comment: Actually it's the same issue as in their github issues list: https://github.com/gateio/gateapi-php/issues/19 it is not a solution, but lower your guzzle version in your composer.json that version 6 is very vulnerable to security problems, so it's not a real solution. See how they resolve the issue in their list, the branches still get commits, so they're active

Comment: @matiaslauriti other packages are compatible with the guzzle-http 7 except the gateio/gateapi-php. That's the problem. If I downgrade/lower my guzzle version to version 6, I will then have multiple conflicts with other packages like pusher-php and cloudinary and others which are also in the project.

Comment: @DestinyB that is the problem, you are in a big trouble, you should upgrade the packages that are not compatible with Guzzle 7, but that could be very difficult if they are very old. There is no magic solution or command solution for this unfortunately. You must either upgrade the non-compatible packages to be compatible with Guzzle 7 (that means going a version up or replacing it with another package) or downgrade the `guzzle` package to 6, but that is not a good idea due to security concerns and maybe then the other packages are not compatible with Guzzle 6 unless you downgrade them...